# How should you schedule tasks in a web api .NET 5 vNext

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

I am in need of scheduling tasks that need to run every hour daily.  I also ideally need to "fire and forget" a task, although i could handle this by creating another task to run every 5 minutes instead.

I have created a WebApi and ideally would like to run a scheduler within this, rather than having to create another application, such as a console app and then setup a windows schedule task. I see that there is a nuget package called Quartz.net that can deal with this.

Quartz sounds good to me, because code is all in one place.  Plus because i will have multiple copies of this webApi running, Quartz could run for each instance.

But overall i want stablility! I have been reading sites and they say because your application pool is recycled by default every X hours, scheduling in a webApi is not a good idea.

Has anyone done this before, and which option did they go for and why?

Comment: http://hangfire.io/ is another alternative. You should check http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx this blog post.